# How to write "should not" see a page in cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, bdd

For example, the user should not see a login page while one has already logged in. How should I implement this functionality in cucumber?

```
Scenario: Authorizzation
  Given I am logged in
  Then I should not be asked to authenticate


Given(/^I am logged in$/) do 
  @user = User.new
end

Then(/^I should not be asked to authenticate$/) do
  # what to write???
end
```

Assume the authentication page is called login.

Comment: Can you provide the code you have got already?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your existing code, its hard to assume.  But it is along these lines

```
Given...do  
  ...
  arg1.should  #=> should
  ...
end

Given...do
  ...    
  arg1.should_not #=> should not
  ...
end
```

#### Update

```
Then(/^I should not be asked to authenticate$/) do
  # what to write???
  unless @user.logged_in?  #=> assumes there is a method that checks it
    routines to login
  end
end
```

From my practical experience, I recommend getting your Ruby basics right to enjoy cucumber.  Besides, it is very useful when scenarios say what **should** happen.

```
Scenario: Authentication
  Given user is not logged in
  Then he should be asked to authenticate  #=> (OR) Then he should be redirected to login page
```

Comment: See my update. I want the logged-in users not able to see the login page.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
page.body.should_not include_text("Please enter your credentials")
```

Comment: There's not a parameter called page though.

Comment: not a parameter. but an object in context of the test. See http://watirmelon.com/2012/06/22/rspec-page-objects-and-user-flows/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are fundamentally approaching it from the wrong direction.  You might instead assert that `I should see` something that you expect like a link, text, or other.  You can also `follow` a link one more level that you can assert you have proper access too.

It's hard to test something that isn't happening and you have no evidence, so test what you expect, not the world of things for which you can't test.

Answer (score 0):

On login page it seems that buttons like "Login" or "Sign In" should be present.
So, after login, you can check whether this button not present.

```
page.should_not have_xpath(:xpath, '//here your xpath to element', :text => "Login")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Then /^(?:|I )should not be on (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  URI.parse(current_url).path.should_not == path_to(page_name)
end
```